# Who burned down the loft in 'Dynasty'?

Tags: plot-explanation, dynasty

In the TV Show 'Dynasty', a Netflix original also airing on The CW... Who burned down the loft in the season one finale? I've googled around and some say it was Hank Sullivan (The con artist who pretended to be Adam, the Carrington's first born), but if he did it... What would be his motive?

Answer (score 1):

I think they settled on Hank as the assailant. As for motive, all that would make sense is anger towards Alexis and the influence of Claudia Blaisdel (the lady that faked being crazy to keep her husband Matthew home, lost Matthew in the CA accident which she caused and blamed everyone else, tries to extort the Carrington's, and kidnaps the baby ... yeah it was whack) Hank was the one to flee the scene with Claudia when she shot Cristal and since this show basically revolves around backstabbing and revenge it would make sense that Claudia tells him to do so as a way to get back at Alexis as an attack on the Carrington's.

In 'Queen of Cups', Claudia is upset at Hank for not extorting money from the Carringtons and that is when he realizes how crazy she actually is.
It could be Alexis who orchestrated the whole plan, but why would she willing tell someone to set the Loft that she was staying in on fire when she was trying to win the house and be a home-wrecker? 'That Witch' shows Alexis giving Hank his payoff, it could have been her but the show never has her explicitly say she ordered him to set the loft ablaze.